# load then write image

Tags: image, opencv, load

I read image using opencv and save it again, but when I read it later the data not be the same, that I mean after I read the image I save it, then copy the saved image and read the data inside this image but the data will not the same as before, I write small code to do the following
1- read image
2- save the image
3- save image data into text file
4- read the saved image fro step 2
5- compare the values of the image to the values of the text file and print them together

my code is

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<math.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include "highgui.h"


    IplImage *PlainImage=0,*CipherImage=0,*DecPlainImage=0;

    void func_printimage()
    {




    // create a window
    cvNamedWindow("Plain Image",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvMoveWindow("Plain Image", 800, 600);
    // show the image
    cvShowImage("Plain Image", PlainImage );

    // wait for a key
    cvNamedWindow("Cipher Image",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvMoveWindow("Cipher Image", 800, 600);

   // show the image
   cvShowImage("Cipher Image", CipherImage );
   cvSaveImage("CipherImage.jpg",CipherImage,0);

   cvWaitKey(0);



 }

  int main()
 {
                    //i j and k used as counters
                    int i,j,step,dep,k,ch,L,C,P,sum=0;
                    uchar *data_byte;
                    //Define CPU time parameters for each Layer
                    PlainImage=cvLoadImage("PlainImage.jpg",3);
                    CipherImage=cvLoadImage("PlainImage.jpg",3);
                    L    = PlainImage->height;
                    C     = PlainImage->width;
                    P  = PlainImage->nChannels;
                    step      = PlainImage->widthStep;
                    data_byte=CipherImage->imageData;
                    printf("Image Information are:\nL=%d\n",L);
                    printf("C=%d\n",C);
                    printf("P=%d\n",P);
                    system("pause");

                    FILE *f1;
                               f1 = fopen ("cipher1.txt", "wt");
                               fprintf(f1,"%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t",L,C,P,CipherImage->depth);
                                    for(k=0;k<L*C*P;k++)
                                    {

                                    fprintf(f1,"%d\t",data_byte[k]);

                                    }
                                    fclose (f1);
                                    func_printimage();
                                    for(k=0;k<L*C*P;k++)
                                    {
                                    data_byte[k]=0;

                                    }


                            f1 = fopen ("cipher1.txt", "rt");

                            fscanf (f1,"%d", &L);
                            fscanf (f1,"%d", &C);
                            fscanf (f1,"%d", &P);
                            fscanf (f1,"%d", &dep);

                    CipherImage=cvLoadImage("CipherImage.jpg",3);
                    data_byte=CipherImage->imageData;
                    printf("Image Information are:\nL=%d\n",L);
                    printf("C=%d\n",C);
                    printf("P=%d\n",P);
                    system("pause");
                            for(k=0;k<L*C*P;k++)
                            {
                                fscanf (f1,"%d", &i);
                                sum+=abs(i-data_byte[k]);
                                printf("i=%d  data=%d\n",i,data_byte[k]);
                            }
                            printf("difference=%d\n",sum);
                            fclose (f1);


                            system("pause");
                     return 0;
}
```

//End  of the main Program

Answer (score 0):

jpg images use [Lossy Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression).
You should use png images.

Comment: But in my project I need jpg format, can I save the image without lossy compression using opencv comands

Comment: jpg images have quality parameter for compression. If you put it to 100% it would theoretically be without loss. See if your save function has an extra parameter for quality.

Comment: Yes, but using openCv I didn't find how can adjust the quality to be 100%, but relevant to your answer I change the image type from JPG into PNG and the function works correctly, but still I need to know how to save jpg image in C code without lossy information

Answer (score 0):

Here in this post i will show you that how to Load an image from your chosen directory and then convert it into gray color, and then store the new one(modified) image in a directory C:\Images.

The code is given below:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>,
using namespace cv;
int main( )
 {

  Mat img;
  img = imread(“C:\\prado.jpg”, 1 );

 if( !img.data )
   {
     printf( ” No image data \n ” );
      return -1;
    }
   else
       prinf(“Your program is working well”);
 Mat gray_image;
 cvtColor( img, gray_image, CV_RGB2GRAY );
 imwrite( “C://images/Gray_Image.jpg”, gray_image);
 imshow( “real image”, img);
 imshow( “Gray image”, gray_image);
 waitKey(0); 
 return 0;
  }
```

**EXPLANATION:**

```
  Mat img = imread(“C:\\prado.jpg”, 1 );
```

this means to get image from my directory and store it in Mat object which is “img” here, actually Mat object store the data of any image.

```
  cvtColor( img, gray_image, CV_RGB2GRAY );
```

This line convert the originial (RGB) into other color image(GRAY)

```
  imwrite( “C://images/Gray_Image.jpg”, gray_image);
```

This one store the new modified image which have been store in Mat object “gray_image” in the directory C://images/ you can chose your own directory